# How to encrypt image name and save into database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I can save the image name into database without any problem but when I try to encrypt the name only the image path gets the encrypted name but the database not

```
public function fileUpload(){

    $clientes = $this->pm->getAllProducts();

    foreach ($clientes as $cliente) {

        $teste = $cliente->id;
    }

    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){

        // Set preference
        $config['upload_path'] = "uploads/";    
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
        $config['max_size']    = '5024'; // max_size in kb
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $config['file_name'] =  $_FILES['file']['name'];

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        //Load upload library
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);     

        $data = array(
            'pub_id' => $teste,
            'url' => $_FILES['file']['name']
        );

        $this->pm->addProduct($data);   

        // File upload
        if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
            // Get data about the file
            $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php you can do with

Comment: this is my fileUpload from my controller, I think to do what I'm looking for just need to implement few things into my code... I'm new in codeigniter

Comment: Try $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; use it

Comment: I sended code ..it working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encrypt file name with config

```
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```

Or

```
$file= uniqid().time().$_FILES["file"]['name'];
$config['file_name'] = $file;
```

Comment: almost there... but I'm getting encrypted name with the image real name in database, what I want is only to get encrypted name in databse.

Comment: Maybe remove cache of browser ,sometimes u cant seem changes

Comment: I tried to make few changes into the code you sent me... thats what I did $file= uniqid().time(); and $config['file_name'] = $file; so now in image path im receiving the name like this 5d7189b766c281567721911.jpg and in database im receiving the same name 5d7189b766c281567721911 but without the image format.

Comment: You can get extensions .$path=   $_FILES['file']['name'];
$extenaion = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); $name='.'.$name;

Comment: Increase size mysql store column ,maybe so can't save to dB

Comment: thats how I fixed $file =$config['file_name'] . '.' . pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: $name=$file.'.'.$extension; as it